# how do get VideoJS to show poster on ended

Tags: video, html5-video

This code does trigger on ended, shows the bigPlayButton but does not show the posterImage ??? anyone know the correct way to accomplish. using videojs 4.3.0

videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){

```
 var vid = this;
 vid.on("ended", function(){
    alert ("I have triggered");
    vid.posterImage.show();
    vid.bigPlayButton.show();
    vid.currentTime(0);
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

here was my solution:

```
        var currvideo = $('.vjs-playing').attr('id')
        if (currvideo){
            var vid = videojs(currvideo);
            vid.pause();    
            vid.posterImage.show();  
            vid.currentTime(0);  
            vid.controlBar.hide();  
            vid.bigPlayButton.show();  
            vid.cancelFullScreen();  
          }
```